# In CNN network, should input image go to all neurons in first convolution layer (I mean first hidden layer) or not?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I am new to CNN topic, I have one basic question regarding mapping between input image with neurons in first convolution  layer.

My question is :
should input image go to all neurons in first convolution layer (I mean first hidden layer) or not ?

For example: if my first hidden layer in CNN as 8 neurons, in that case complete input image  is passed to all these 8 neurons or only set of pixels of input image is passed to each neuron.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you understand what you are asking because the number of neurons in a convolutional layer is something that you don't concern yourself too much with unless you are building your own implementation of a CNN.

To answer your question - No, each neuron in the first convolutional layer is connected only to pixels in its own receptive field (given by kernel size) and the same logic also applies to next convolutional layers as well except now they are connected to lower layer neurons in their receptive field.

> For example: if my first hidden layer in CNN as 8 neurons

How do you know that it has 8 neurons? Unless you are doing some low level CNN programming, you do not specify the number of neurons. The number of neurons that you need is usually given by a combination of `kernel size`, `stride`, type of `padding` and the amount of `filters` that you have chosen to use. These 4 things (together with input size of the image) tells you exactly how many neurons you need.

For example, in Keras (since you have tagged this question with tensorflow) you might see convolutional layer like this one:

```py
keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation="relu",
                    input_shape=(100, 100, 1))
```

As you can see, you don't specify anything like the number of neurons here (at least not directly). Under this settings, you end up with output whose width and height are cropped by 2 (due to the default padding) so the output shape of this layer is (128, 98, 98) (technically it has a shape of (None, 128, 98, 98) where None is for batch size). If you would flatten this and feed the output into a single neuron (let's say in a dense layer), you would end up with 128 * 98 * 98 = 1,229,313 weights just between these two layers.

So for the analogy between dense and convolutional layer, the above convolutional layers with 128 filters connected to one output neuron is similar to having dense layer with 1,229,313 neurons connected to one output neuron.

Comment: Thanks for your kind responses. Still i am not clear what is  relationship between kernel/filters and neurons with respect convolution layer. I am aware of padding and strides concepts, But one thing not clear to me is when neurons in the first constitutional layer is connected only to pixels in its own receptive field (given by kernel size), then point of strides operation since  kernel size and connected pixels size is same.

Comment: Kernel size and connected pixels size is indeed the same but if you increase the value of stride then the number of neurons in that layer decreases. Therefore, you are decreasing the amount of trainable parameters (weights) given that you don't change the number of filters. As for the relationship between neurons and filters, each neuron produces one output per filter, therefore if you have 128 filters, one neuron will produce 128 distinct outputs. But you can have as many filters as you want. This number does not depend on the number of neurons that you have - but the complexity may explode.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I got it now,number of filters is independent of number of neurons in convolution layer.
But, Let say i have input image of size 3*3*1, kernel size is 2*2 and no padding. It means each neuron in convolution layer get portion of input image which is size of 2*2 pixels, Now Each neuron performs conv operation over this portion of input image. Since input image portion and kernel size is same, We will get one output.But if we perform striding operation by one step(stride= 1), We will cross the boundary of portion input image, Which is something we don't  need right ?

Comment: One more question how portion of input image is mapped to each neuron ? I mean how do i know which portion of input image is mapped which neuron.
Please clarify with some example, I am really stuck here. Thanks in advance

Comment: Stride = 1 means that you are sliding the kernel one pixel at a time. Let's consider `x` axis and number pixels 1, 2, and 3. The first neuron will see pixels 1 and 2, then the kernel is shifted by one pixel and the next neuron will see pixels 2 and 3. This happens if you use `valid` padding. In case of `same` padding, first neuron will see pixels 1 and 2, the second neuron will see pixels 2, 3 and the third neuron will see pixels 3 and (one zero padded). In case the second case, you end up with the output of the same size as the image (3 x 3 x 1). In the former case, the output is (2 x 2 x 1)

Comment: Thanks lot @Matus Dubrava for clarification. It means each neuron will use n number of filter to learn the insight behind the particular portion of the input image. which also means number of neuron is depends on input image size, Kernel_size , padding and stride operations right ?

Comment: That is exactly correct. Just one more thing, individual filters are shared by all neurons which means that the network doesn't have to learn `n` filters for each individual neuron, rather it learns `n` filters in total and each neuron will apply the the same `n` transformations to its receptive field. That is one of the reasons why CNNs are computationally more efficient than dense networks (given image recognition task).